# Data read from one drive through ADF

Tags: excel, azure, etl, onedrive, oracle-adf

It is possible to fetch data from one drive to SQL database by the help of Azure Data Factory

I am trying to copy the Excel files from One drive (Which have multiple folder) , but there is no inbuild connector in ADF to do this activity . I have tried with sharepoint and Microsoft office 365 connector but did not able to that from the One drive

Comment: No, There is no inbuilt connector in ADF to connect One Drive You can Copy data from one Drive to Azure Blob using Power Automate and copy that data to Sql database using ADF.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/580647/excel-onedrive-to-blob-with-azure-data-factory) there is no inbuilt connector in Azure data factory to connect One drive. But as an alternative you can use [Power Automate](https://make.preview.powerautomate.com/galleries/public/templates/49933434732d4846a1fc0aaae72f8998/copy-new-files-to-azureblob-from-a-onedrive-for-business-folder) to copy data from one drive to Azure blob storage.
Connect Azure blob storage with Access key authentication:

[image]

Connect to One Drive account

[image]

Select files Source and destination:

[image]

By using Copy activity in ADF you can copy data from blob storage to Sql database.
Copy data Json to Copy multiple tables from Blob to SQL database:

```
  {
        "name": "pipeline1",
        "properties": {
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "Lookup1",
                    "type": "Lookup",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "policy": {
                        "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                        "retry": 0,
                        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                        "secureOutput": false,
                        "secureInput": false
                    },
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "source": {
                            "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                            "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES\nWHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'",
                            "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                            "partitionOption": "None"
                        },
                        "dataset": {
                            "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable2",
                            "type": "DatasetReference"
                        },
                        "firstRowOnly": false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "ForEach1",
                    "type": "ForEach",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        {
                            "activity": "Lookup1",
                            "dependencyConditions": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "items": {
                            "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value\n",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "isSequential": true,
                        "activities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Copy data1",
                                "type": "Copy",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "policy": {
                                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                    "retry": 0,
                                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                    "secureOutput": false,
                                    "secureInput": false
                                },
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "source": {
                                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                                        "partitionOption": "None"
                                    },
                                    "sink": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                        "storeSettings": {
                                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                        },
                                        "formatSettings": {
                                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                            "quoteAllText": true,
                                            "fileExtension": ".csv"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "enableStaging": false,
                                    "translator": {
                                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                        "typeConversion": true,
                                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "inputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "Schema": {
                                                "value": "@item().TABLE_SCHEMA",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            },
                                            "tableName": {
                                                "value": "@item().TABLE_NAME",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": [
                                    {
                                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "annotations": []
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , getting the warning message during of creating power automate :-
-> sign up for 90 days free trial 
-> Send a license request to your admin

Comment: Also , power automate is only used when new file is uploaded , then what about the existing files that are stored in one drive .