# Need to Copy Folder from Onedrive Online to Azure Storage Gen 2 without local download

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, onedrive, azure-synapse

I need to copy Folders of large files, each file above 150Mb to Azure ADLS. I was trying to use Synapse or Power Automate but haven't found any connector that does the job without having to download all files.

I am after a solution that I share a OneDrive link and copy files directly.

Anyone can share some ideas how best to achieve this pls either programmatically/scripts or use Microsoft tools?

Comment: Please see this answer about using power automate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76063001/data-read-from-one-drive-through-adf#:~:text=No%2C%20There%20is%20no%20inbuilt,to%20Sql%20database%20using%20ADF.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedrive/#known-issues-and-limitations) in Power Automate, when a file is created or modified, triggers will skip any file larger than 50 MB. Thus, it is preferable to use a logic app to copy files that are greater than 150 MB.

Create a logic app and use the `List files in folder` action. Sign in to OneDrive and select the folder as shown below:

[image]

Add a foreach action and select Value as an output from the previous step, as shown below:

[image]

Add a "get file content" action in foreach and configure it as shown below:

[image]

Add a "Create blob" action to the "get file content" and connect to the Azure Data Lake Storage account with access key authentication, as shown below:

[image]

Afterward, provide the details as shown below:

[image]

Run the logic app, and it will run successfully, as shown below:

[image]

It will copy data from OneDrive to ADLS, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the time taken to reply in great detail.
However in my case, I have a shared link and not synced to my pc. So step 1 is not possible.
I was after a connector that accepts the Onedrive URL link and having to sync to my pc.

Comment: If you have a shared link to a file on OneDrive and you don't want to sync it to your local PC, but rather access it through a connector in Azure Data Factory, you can use the "HTTP" or "Web" connector to access and work with the file